# How can I make a random selection from an inversely-weighted list?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given a list of integers, e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4`, I know how to select items based on their weight. The example items would have probabilities of 10%, 20%, 30%, and 40%, respectively.

Is there an equally simple method of selecting items based on the inverse of their weight? With this method, the example list would be equal to a weighted list of `1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4` (48%, 24%, 16%, 12%), but I want to avoid the conversion and use of floating-point arithmetic. (Assume all of the integers are positive and non-zero.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could divide the numbers' [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) by each number and get integral proportions.

For `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, this is 12. Your weights are 12/1=12, 12/2=6, 12/3=4, 12/4=3.

You could also multiply them all together and not bother with the LCM as well. The numbers will be higher but the proportions will be the same: 24/1=24, 24/2=12, 24/3=8, 24/4=6.

Comment: I *just* came up with this solution. All it took was writing it down again and thinking for a few minutes.

Comment: Don't worry I will. I've gotta wait 4 more minutes tho. =P

Comment: The problem with this method is that for large `n`, you will run into integer overflow issues. Even for a 64-bit long, this will fail for `n` on the order of 25.

Comment: Well, the assumption is that for bigger numbers, one would use data types which can avoid that. Most languages have bignum support at least in a library.

Answer (score 0):

First get the sum of the weights, call it `S` (e.g. `1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 = 2.083`). Then to find the probability of weight `w_i`, you divide `w_i` by `S` (e.g. `1/2.083 = 48%`.

I don't think there's a nice, closed-form formula for this expression for general sequences of numbers.

The sum of the weights are [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). For large `n`, the sum converges to `ln(n)+gamma` where gamma is the Euler–Mascheroni constant (~0.577). So for large `n`, you could use this formula to approximate the sum.

EDIT: There are ways to reduce floating point errors. One such way is to calculate the sum from the smallest term up to the largest term (e.g. `1/n + 1/(n-1) + ... + 1`). This allows the intermediate calculations to maximize the number of bits of precision. By doing this, rounding issues should not be a problem.

Comment: This is exactly the type of floating-point arithmetic operations I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.